# Bind v-model dynamically in v-for loop using string as a model name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to render several components using `<component v-bind:is="...">` in a `v-for` loop. That works well, now I need to assign `v-model` in the loop.

This is what I have - an array of objects, each object represents component, with it's props, and the **model**

```js
let formA = [{
        component: 'formPartA',
        props: {
            value1: true,
            value2: "Hello",
        },
        model: "formData.formA" // This is what I need to use in the loop

    },
    {
        component: 'formPartB',
        props: {
            value1: true,
        },
        model: "formData.formB"

    },
];
```

The data:

```js
data() {
    return {
        form: formA,
        formData: {
            formA: null,
            formB: null,
        },
    }
}
```

So far I was able to render it succesfully:

```html
<template v-for="(c, index) in form">
    <component
        v-bind:is="c.component"
        v-bind="c.props"
    ></component>
</template>
```

The components are working with the props defined in the array. All I want now is to add the `v-model`, however I can't get this to work.

I tried to bind it:

```html
v-model="c.model"
:v-model="c.model"
```

or alter the `c.model`

```
model: "formData.formA"
model: formData.formA
model: this.formData.formA
```

and nothing works for me.

I even tried [a workaround](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) to just rewrite `v-model` to `v-bind:value` with `v-on:input`, this didn't work either.

I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Well it looks like I just found a solution to my problem:

```
v-model="formData[c.model]"
```

In the `let formA = ...`

```js
model: "formA"
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        form: formA,
        formData: {
            formA: null,
            formB: null,
        }, 
    }
}
```